# My singleton can be called multiple times

Tags: android, c++, singleton, hal

I have implemented an singleton based on c++ 11.
However the constructor can be called multiple times in some cases.

The class will be compiled to static lib and 
used by other so lib (more than one so lib).
And the system is a multi-thread system (run in the Android HAL level)

/// The .h file:

```
class Logger
{
public:

    /// Return the singleton instance of Logger
    static Logger& GetInstance() {
        static Logger s_loggerSingleton;
        return s_loggerSingleton;
    }

private:

    /// Constructor
    Logger();
    /// Destructor
    ~Logger();
}
```

/// the .cpp file

```
Logger::Logger()
{
   ALOGE("OfflineLogger create");
}

Logger::~Logger()
{

}
```

It should be created once eg:

```
03-21 01:52:20.785   728  4522 E         : OfflineLogger create
```

However I can see it has been created more than once

```
03-21 01:52:20.785   728  4522 E         : OfflineLogger create
03-21 01:52:20.863   728  2274 E         : OfflineLogger create
03-21 01:52:20.977   728  2273 E         : OfflineLogger create
03-21 01:52:26.370   728  4522 E         : OfflineLogger create
```

Questions:

1. Anything wrong with my singleton design? Is it a thread-safe issue?
2. Seems like my singleton works fine in one so scope, but each 
   so lib which includes my singleton will create its own singleton, so that my 
   singleton is no longer “be a singleton”. Is the problem caused from each 
   dynamic linking to new so and the "static variable" becomes "local static"? 
   Is it possible? If so, how to fix?

Comment: Don't forget to delete the copy constructor, otherwise it's easy to create multiple objects. It's a good idea to delete assignment, although it might not harm you too much to assign the object to itself

Comment: Also don't forget that there's no synchronization employed here, so it's still prone to race conditions if it's ever used in a multi-threaded context.

Comment: @Alexander That applies to using the object and not to creating it, though. Since C++11, function-scope static variables are guaranteed to be initialised race-free.

Comment: @Angew Woah, really? They finally have a purpose! That's great to hear

Comment: Here's an idea: Rather than use a singleton, which is both a hard problem in your environment and [known to be problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons) for testing and maintenance, just design your code to only create one of the object in question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> 1. Anything wrong with my singleton design? Is it a thread-safe issue?

No. Initialization of function local `static` variables is guaranteed to be thread-safe by the standard.

> 2. Seems like my singleton works fine in one so scope, but each 
>      so lib which include my singleton will create its own singleton, so that my 
>      singleton is no longer “be a singleton”. Is the problem caused from each 
>      dynamic linking to new so and the "staic veriable" become "local static"? 
>      Is it possible? If so, how to fix

That is the correct conclusion.

Instead of creating a static library that contains the implementation of the singleton, make it a dynamic library.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. Finally I change to use dynamic linking and works fine

Comment: @hismart, you are welcome. Glad I was able to help.

Comment: But why multiple so will cause such problem?

Comment: @BaiyanHuang, because each so will have its own copy of the static library built into it.

Answer (score 4):

Singletons are hard, especially with shared libraries.

Each of your shared libraries has an independent copy of the non-shared library.  Without extra care, each will have a copy of the singleton.

In order to have non-trivial singletons, what I have had to do was

1. Create an extremely low level library to help with singletons -- call it LibSingleton
2. Create a singleton template that knows the type of the singleton.  It uses magic statics to send a request to the LibSingleton with a size, `typeid(T).name()` key, and type-erased construction and destruction code.  LibSingleton returns a reference counting RAII object.
3. LibSingleton uses a shared mutex to either return a previously constructed object that matches the name/size or constructs it.  If it constructs the object, it stores the destruction code.
4. When the last reference-counted handle to the LibSingleton data goes away, LibSingleton runs the destruction code and cleans up the memory in its unordered map.

This permits really simple singletons to be used nearly anywhere.

```
template<class T>
class singleton {
public:
  static T& Instance() {
    static auto smart_ptr = LibSingleton::RequestInstance(
      typeid(T).name(),
      sizeof(T),
      [](void* ptr){ return ::new( ptr ) T{}; },
      [](void* ptr){ static_cast<T*>(ptr)->~T(); }
    );
    if (!smart_ptr)
      exit(-1); // or throw something
    return *static_cast<T*>(smart_ptr.get());
  }
protected:
  singleton() = default;
  ~singleton() = default;
private:
  singleton(singleton&&) = delete;
  singleton& operator=(singleton&&) = delete;
};
```

use looks like:

```
struct Logger : LibSingleton::singleton<Logger> {
  friend class LibSingleton::singleton<Logger>;
  void do_log( char const* sting ) {}
private:
  Logger() { /* ... */ }
};
```

Comment: It looks like most of the effort is spent to get the first singleton, and others are relatively easy to add. Still, it makes one wonder ...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea:Rather than use a singleton,which is both a hard problem in your environment and known to be problematic for testing and maintenance,just design your code to only create one of the object in question.

Comment: Simple but true... :)

Answer (score 1):

static variable should be moved to .cpp file.

Simple way is to keep only declaration of getInstance() in .h and move implementation to .cpp file.

Comment: That won't help at all. Even inline functions are guaranteed to have only one set of statics. The problem here is with the shared libraries.

Comment: @AngewisnolongerproudofSO I was just having this issue and moving the definition of GetInstance to the cpp file worked for me. I suspect it prevents each library from keeping it's own copy by moving the ownership to only the library that contains the implementation. I'm not sure how portable this is; just pointing out that it worked for my test case on Windows with MinGW.